# Endless huawei error logs in Google + Huawei project

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, huawei-mobile-services

I am using the G+H solution in the project I am working on in order to support huawei and google devices. I have both google and huawei libraries in the same project and I decide which services should be used based on HuaweiApiAvailability and GoogleApiAvailability classes. Everything works fine for each of the two service cases; maps, notifications, redirection urls in stores etc.

My only concern is when I run the code and I have an error in the code (any). In that case, the logcat fills endlessly with huawei error logs, which keep appearing the same again and again without reason (see attached screenshot). If the app does not get killed, the default android studio exception log (the analytic one, which addresses the line in the code etc) of course disappears after a while.

I don't like the simple and obvious solution to filter somehow the logcat results or kill the app. I would like to know why the same error gets reported endlessly by huawei in the logcat and if there is a way to avoid / limit this behaviour.

I guess what I describe above happens also when we have only hms in our project (difference is that in G+H approach we also have endless messages like "Failed to find HMS apk" etc when running on non-huawei device). It seems some sort of huawei libraries error. Could the messages appear once?

[image]

Comment: Please do not post logcat output in screen shots. It is test you can simply copy and paste into your question.

Comment: Just to clarify. I am not asking how to solve the error that I got. I intentionally put an error in the code, in order to show that huawei reports the same error over and over again. That' s the problem.

Comment: For non-Huawei device better create a flavor that does not include the Huawei library. Besides that I would report that to Huawei and hope for a fix.